# How to Lock and unlock android phone remotely using php server

Tags: android

I am new to android, and I wanted to connect my phone remotely using php and do operations for Lock and unlock android phone. E.g I lock/unlock my phone from php website

Answer (score -1):

I don't get your purpose of doing it, maybe your trying to have a remote control of your mobile phone. I don't know if theres an existing library for it but I think of a few ways to do it. You can use GCM(Google cloud messaging) so that you can have a reference of the phone you would want to lock. In your app you should handle a message sent from your api(Php) or your website to lock or unlock the your phone.

[GCM Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)